# How to send large amount of email in backgroup process

Tags: php, email, drupal-7, drupal-modules, mime-mail

I have Drupal website and i created a custom menu in my custom module.

I need to send email to 10000 users with different email greeting lines. I am fetching each user profile information and then send email to each user.

But the problem is that it takes huge time to complete the request sometimes it give request timeout error.

So i want such kind of functionality that i can get the response with in few seconds and all emails will be running on background process.

Any Idea?

Comment: Think about using some external service, like i.e. mailchimp. I'm afraid that your ip address will be black listed after sending so many emails...

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a cron, running in every 3/5/7 etc mins on server. Then in each run you can send emails to 100, 200, 500 no of users with a flag set to reduce the duplicate. You can choose no of users depending on your server execution time. However, i assume 500 is a good no to start with and it will take only 20 cron runs to send all 10k emails.

And/Or you could use a third-party services like mailchimp, sendgrid etc to schedule emails.

Hope it will help!

Comment: But i want to send these emails manually without cron-job, as i have menu link so that when i click on that link then it will send email

Comment: Ok, then you should use the batch processing using Batch API provided in Drupal https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview.

Comment: See this: "Functions allowing forms processing to be spread out over several page requests, thus ensuring that the processing does not get interrupted because of a PHP timeout, while allowing the user to receive feedback on the progress of the ongoing operations."